# How do I create an app config service to configure ngbTooltips in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

All,

I am trying to keep my app component clean and was hoping to create an app config service to globally set my ngbTooltips.

In my app component (app.component.ts) I have the following

```
@Component({
  selector: 'root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  providers: [NgbTooltipConfig]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private readonly appConfigService: AppConfigService
  ) {}   

 ngOnInit() {}
}
```

And in my app config service (app.config.service.ts), I have the following

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppConfigService {
  constructor(private readonly ngbTooltipConfig: NgbTooltipConfig) {
    ngbTooltipConfig.placement = 'bottom';
    ngbTooltipConfig.container = 'body';
  }
}
```

When I hover over a ngbTooltip, it always has it's placement as 'top'?

What am I missing?  I am injecting AppConfigService into AppComponent so shouldn't tooltip placement be 'bottom' everywhere?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I figured out my issue.

I shouldn't have had

```
providers: [NgbTooltipConfig]
```

in app component.

Thx